# VF Form Redirects on Submit but Doesn't Save

Tags: visualforce

I created a VF Page that redirects upon submit, but now does not save/create a new 'intake' object as expected. Why?

Here is my VF page code

```
<apex:page standardController="Intake__c" extensions="IntakeExtension" standardStyleSheets="false" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
    
  
  <link REL="Favicon" HREF="{!URLFOR($Resource.favicon)}"/>  
  <apex:stylesheet value="{!$Resource.styleForIntake}"/>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
   
  
  
<body>
<!-- multistep form -->
<apex:form Id="msform" styleClass="form">

  <!-- fieldsets -->
 <br></br><br></br>
   <fieldset>
   <br></br><br></br>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Client Information</h2> 
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Here, we will gather information specific to the client.</h3> <br>

    <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" styleClass="submit action-button" style="width=100px" value="Submit" id="saveButton" />
     </fieldset>
     
     
     <fieldset>
           <p> Thank you for your submission </p>
           
     </fieldset> 
    
 
</apex:form>
</body>
</apex:page>
```

Here is my controller code

```
public with sharing class IntakeExtension {
    public IntakeExtension(ApexPages.StandardController Intake) {
    }
    public PageReference save() {
        return Page.Congratulations;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to leverage the built-in save functionality provided by the StandardController, your controller's markup should call that function and then redirect on success (look at the `PageMessages` VF tag for display of errors).

```
public with sharing class IntakeExtension {
    public ApexPages.StandardController yourController { get; set; }
    
    public IntakeExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        yourController = controller;
    }

    public PageReference save() {
        yourController.save(); // don't forget to handle errors and show them to the user

        return Page.Congratulations;
    }
}
```